# Java 8 find element matching in a list of objects where each object has another object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have two classes:

```
class SampleClass {
   private String testString;
   private List<Label> labels; 
}
```

```
class Label {
   private String labelName;
   private String labelValue;
}
```

I have a `List<SampleClass> sampleClassList`. I need to find the find element in the list which has a particular  `labelName` and `labelValue` using Java 8.

If I need to get the `SampleClass` object based on `testString` I would do,

```
Optional<SampleClass> sampleClass = sampleClassList.stream().filter(entry -> entry.getTestString().equals("some_value").findFirst();
```

Now that the filtering involves `Label` class, I am unable to figure out how to do that. I have tried something like,

```
Optional<SampleClass> sampleClass = sampleClassList.stream().filter(entry -> 
                                       entry.getLabels().stream().filter(label -> 
                                            label.getName().equals("some_name") && 
                                            label.getValue().equals("some_value")).findFirst()).findFirst();
```

for which I get `Bad return type in lambda expression: Optional<Label> cannot be converted to boolean`. How would I go about making this change?

I could make it work by using `contains()` method

```
final Optional<SampleClass> sampleClass = sampleClassList.stream()
                    .filter(entry -> entry.getLabels()
                            .contains(new Label().withLabelName("some_name").withLabelValue("some_value")))
                    .findFirst();
```

but would like to know if I can still use `stream()` to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Instead of the suggested `findFirst().isPresent()` you can just use `anyMatch()`

```java
public class Label {
  private String name;
  private String value;

  public Label(String name, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Label{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", value='" + value + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

```java
class SampleClass {
  private String testString;
  private List<Label> labels;

  public SampleClass(String testString, List<Label> labels) {
    this.testString = testString;
    this.labels = labels;
  }

  public List<Label> getLabels() {
    return labels;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "SampleClass{" + "testString='" + testString + '\'' + ", labels=" + labels + '}';
  }
}
```

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SampleClass> sampleClassList = List.of(
      new SampleClass("111", List.of(new Label("one", "one value"), new Label("two", "two value"))),
      new SampleClass("222", List.of(new Label("one", "one value"), new Label("two", "two value"))),
      new SampleClass("333", List.of(new Label("some_name", "some_value"), new Label("two", "two value")))
    );
    Optional<SampleClass> sampleClass = sampleClassList.stream()
      .filter(entry ->
        entry.getLabels().stream()
          .anyMatch(label ->
            label.getName().equals("some_name") &&
              label.getValue().equals("some_value")
          )
      )
      .findFirst();
    System.out.println(sampleClass.orElse(null));
  }
}
```

This should print:

```
SampleClass{testString='333', labels=[Label{name='some_name', value='some_value'}, Label{name='two', value='two value'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error message because

```
label -> label.getName().equals("some_name") && label.getValue().equals("some_value")).findFirst()
```

returns an Optional when Java needs a boolean for your outer filter. Essentially you're saying give me an Optional that contains the value if it exists. If you change the findFirst() to isPresent() then that will give you the boolean you need as isPresent() just says return true if the value exists.

Comment: `isPresent()` method in `Stream`?

Comment: _"If you change the `findFirst()` to `isPresent()`"_ - sorry no, that does not work. You would have to change it to `findFirst().isPresent()`, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
sampleClassList.stream().filter(entry ->
                entry.getLabels().stream().filter(label ->
                        label.getName().equals("some_name") &&
                                label.getValue().equals("some_value")).count() > 0).findFirst();
```

use count() > 0 after filtering on inner labels List

Comment: For long streams this is suboptimal because in order to count you have to read the whole stream. Instead, in this case you want to stop at the first (or any) matching element.